# Скрипт работает на localhost, но не на VPS

Tags: php, vps, localhost, paypal, mamp

Сделал скрипт для *PayPal API*. На `localhost` работает.

Перенес все модули *Apache* и *PHP* на *VPS* и пытаюсь завести скрипт, не получается.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: У меня не получается считать ваш скрипт из вашей головы на расстоянии. Вы пользуетесь шапочкой из фольги? В любом случае, вам прийдется добавить в вопрос хоть какие-то данные о том, что вы делаете.

Answer (score 1):

1. Когда вы переводили скрипт, вы проверяли прямые пути? многие `script`ы при установке берут прямые пути папок
2. Проверьте имя файлов. Возможно вы не учли литералы название файла. На `Linux`е прописные и маленькие буквы отличаются.